# ¿Como lograr que un JScrollPane controle dos componentes?

Tags: java, jframe

Hola estoy creando un compilador, tengo dos componentes un JEditorPane que sirve para escribir el código y al lado izquierdo de este tengo un JTextArea que sirve para ver la cantidad de líneas usadas hasta ese momento.

[image: ventana compilador]

El JScrollPane se encarga de desplazar el contenido del JEditorPane, pero ¿Hay alguna forma de conectar mi JScrollPane a mi JTextArea para que pueda ver los números de cada línea incluso después de llegar al final del JEditorPane ?

Este es mi código:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class Compilador extends JFrame implements Permitidos{
    
    private JPanel panel;
    private JEditorPane editor;
    protected static JTextArea salida;
    private JScrollPane barraEditor, barraSalida;
    private JTextArea lineas;
    protected static String resultados;
    private int nlineas;
   
  
  
    public Compilador(){
        setSize(900,600);
        setTitle("Mi mini compilador");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(Compilador.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        resultados="";
        nlineas=1;
        Panel();
    
    }
    
    private void Panel(){
        panel=new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        AreasTexto_Etiquetas();
            
    }
    
   
    private void AreasTexto_Etiquetas(){
        
        editor=new JEditorPane();
        editor.setFont(new Font("Arial Black",Font.PLAIN,14));
        editor.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
      
        lineas=new JTextArea();
        lineas.setBounds(100,40,20,320);
        lineas.setFont(new Font("Arial Black",Font.PLAIN,14));
        lineas.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        lineas.setBackground(Color.blue);
        lineas.setEditable(false);
        lineas.setText(String.valueOf(nlineas));
        
        panel.add(lineas);
       
       
        barraEditor=new JScrollPane(editor);
        barraEditor.setBounds(120,40,780,320);
        barraEditor.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        barraEditor.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
       
        
     
        salida=new JTextArea();
        salida.setFont(new Font("Arial Black",Font.BOLD,16));
        salida.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        salida.setEditable(false);
        salida.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        
        barraSalida=new JScrollPane(salida);
        barraSalida.setBounds(100,420,800,105);
        barraSalida.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        barraSalida.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        
        
        panel.add(barraEditor);
        panel.add(barraSalida);
       
      
        eventos();
    }
    
    private void eventos(){
         
       KeyListener escrito=new KeyListener(){
           
           @Override
           public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { }

           @Override
           public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
             
           
           }
           
           @Override
           public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
               
               
               if(e.getKeyChar()=='\n'){
                   nlineas++;
                   lineas.setText(lineas.getText()+"\n"+nlineas);
               }
               
            
          
           }
       };
       
       editor.addKeyListener(escrito);
       
   
      
    }
}
```

Espero haber sido claro, de antemano gracias

Comment: en el JScrollPane debe haber una propiedad que varia cada vez que se hace Scroll, en el listener de ese evento podrias 1 obtener el valor de ese ScrollPane, y 2 setear ese mismo valor, en tu segundo JScrollPane, es una idea nada mas

Comment: De hecho, pensé en algo así, pero la verdad desconozco si hay una propiedad que sirva para verificar si un JScrollPane esta desplazado, investigaré un poco si existe